# Check if results from LINQ query contains a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a LINQ query that brings back all records from a table called Permissions, where the userId is the current user.

What I want to do is run a check on this result set and see if PermissionId of value 5 exists..

Whats the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Start by including the current Linq query you have in the question, please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var PermissionIDFiveCount=YourInitialDataset.Where(p=>p.PermissionID==5).Count()
```

Or shorter way:

```
var PermissionIDFiveCount=YourInitialDataset.Count(p=>p.PermissionID==5)
```

Even shorter:

```
var ContainsPermissionIDFive=YourInitialDataset.Any(p=>p.PermissionID==5)
```

Answer (score 17):

```
bool contains_id_5; 
contains_id_5 = Permissions.Where(p=>p.PermissionID==5).Count() > 0;
contains_id_5 = Permissions.Where(p=>p.PermissionID==5).Any();
contains_id_5 = Permissions.Where(p=>p.PermissionID==5).FirstOrDefault() != null;
contains_id_5 = Permissions.Any(p=>p.PermissionID==5);
```

Which one you use depends on whether you have any use for the intermediate bits (the count, the record) or not. `Permissions.Any(p=>p.PermissionID==5)` can be the most efficient with Queryable type LINQ collections, especially as part of a larger query, since it can turn into a SQL `EXISTS` call if you're not using any of the other bits.

Comment: I have a DataTable that I want to cycle and check if the record exists on the database already..   I'll go for the Permissions.Any I think..

Answer (score 2):

If you're returning an IQueryable, just query the results for what you want.

```
var results = repository.GetAllPermissions(id);

var result2 = from r in results where r.PermissionID == 5 select r;

bool contains5 = result2.Count() > 0;
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
var contains5 = repository.GetAllPermissions(id).Count(c => c.PermissionID == 5) > 0;
```

Comment: bool contains5 = result2.Any();

Answer (score 2):

More advanced way can be just by modifying Random832's code as follows.

```
bool contains_id_5; 
contains_id_5 = Permissions.Count(p=>p.PermissionID==5) > 0;
contains_id_5 = Permissions.Any(p=>p.PermissionID==5);
contains_id_5 = Permissions.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.PermissionID==5) != null;
```