# linq Count with checking strings StartWith

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, count, startswith

now i my code when Name entry is duplicate it counts the duplicate names & add the count number next to the name like

if database has 'Andy' Name already then
next Andy will be added as 'Andy 1'

but the problem is if i add another 'Andy' to database it checks for duplicate when its find 'Andy' it becomes 'Andy 1' but again it find 'Andy 1' so at last it get saved as 'Andy 1 1' so i cant figures out how to make it get save by 'Andy 1' then 'Andy 2' then 'Andy 3'

```
private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (DBDataContext DB = new DBDataContext(strConnectionString))
        {
            Table newTable = new Table
            {
                Name = txtName.Text.ToString(),
                Add = txtAdd.Text.ToString(),
            };

            var a = from b in DB.GetTable<Table>() select b;

            foreach (var x in a)
            {
                if (x.Name == txtName.Text.ToString())
                {
                    txtCOUNT.Text = a.Count(b => b.Name == txtName.Text).ToString();

                    MessageBox.Show("This Name is already Exists");

                    Check = txtName.Text + " " + txtCOUNT.Text;

                    txtName.Text = Check;

                    txtAdd.Text = " ";

                    id = x.Id;
                }
            }

            if (txtName.Text != "" && txtAdd.Text != "")
            {
                DB.NTable.InsertOnSubmit(newTable);

                DB.SubmitChanges();

                MessageBox.Show("Name Added Successfully.", "Done!", MessageBoxButton.OK);

                NavigationService.GoBack();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Some essential details must be entered. Name, Add.", "Details Missing!", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
        }
    }
```

i am trying to use strings StartsWith in Counting like

```
string Check = txtName.Text;

txtCOUNT.Text = a.Count (b => b.Name == Check.StartsWith(b.Name)).ToString();
```

but no its giving me error PLEASE HELP

Comment: Go through this link might help 


[Linq check if contains a data][1]


and

[Check start with][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697580/check-if-results-from-linq-query-contains-a-value
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916093/linq-wherex-x-containsstring-that-start-with-foo

Comment: check if any one helps

Comment: no its still not clear i am able to check the StartsWith & count separately but not both together i want both of them work together I guess then only its going to work

Comment: And if someone is really named "Andy 1", do you want to add "Andy 2" or "Andy 1 1"? Or won't this case ever happen?

Comment: i am not saying someone will keep andy 1 their name i am saying when app find out Andy is already saved then app will change it to Andy 1 so basically there are two names like 'Andy' & 'Andy 1' so u tell me if 3 person adds name Andy it will automatically change to the 'Andy 1' because app found 'Andy' before then when saving 3 persons name as 'Andy 1' it will again found 'Andy 1' in the database so it will change it to 'Andy 1 1' haha come on buddy think @KooKiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note is that when you do :

```
var a = from b in DB.GetTable<Table>() select b;

foreach (var x in a)
{
```

It's going to load every row (instead of effecting a db query) which could be costly if there is a lot of row.

Here is a Linq query which i think will do what you want (it will work if the name in `txtName.Text` contains only text):

```
using (DBDataContext DB = new DBDataContext(strConnectionString))
{
            string name = txtName.Text.ToString(),
            int nbDuplicate = (from b in DB.GetTable<Table>()
                    where b.Name==name ||  b.Name.StartsWith(name+" ") 
                       && (b.Name.Length>=name.Length+2 && 
                    b.Name[name.Length+1]>='0'
                    && b.Name[name.Length+1]<='9'
                      )
                    select b).Count();
            name +=  " " + nbDuplicate;
              .....
}
```

Comment: First it gave me error about it but when i did this *****int nbDuplicate = (from b in xCryptoDB.GetTable<AccountsTable>() where b.Extra.StartsWith(name) && (b.Extra == name || (b.Extra.Length > name.Length + 2)) select b).Count();**** its giving me list like AndyAndy 0, AndyAndy 1, AndyAndy 2

Comment: A little typo it's name +=  " " + nbDuplicate;

Comment: yup i tried that already if i use name += " " + nbDuplicate; then its saving all the andy as andy 0 & if use name += name + " " + nbDuplicate; its working like I wanted  but its save name as AndyAndy 0 AndyAndy1 AndyAndy 2

Comment: I just updated it again to fix the problem with IsDigit not supported in Linq to sql. Instead I detect that there is a space at the end, but it just mean that it will currently only work if the name in input cannot contain space

Comment: working correctly but adding the name twice and them adding the no

Comment: Can you have name with space in it?

Comment: ohh thank god its working like exactly i wanted & its even working with space in input THANK YOU

Comment: the problem if you allow space in input is that if you have and user name "andi test" and an user named "andi" when you test the number of andi you will get: the number of "andi" + the number of "andi test"

Comment: what if i add condition in which after name+" " there is only 1 or two characters?

Comment: I guess that depend on what you think the max number of the same user can be

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37396/discussion-between-xsheru-and-benoit-catherinet)

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query

```
var countNumber = (from c in svcContext.ContactSet
                     where c.FirstName.StartsWith("Andy")
                     select new
                     {
                      c.FirstName,
                      c.LastName
                     }).Count();
```

And since this returns an observeable collectionset then we will obviously call the count to get the no of elements. Count in Linq to Sql is achieved like that only no Linq query for count.

Check Msdn link

[Count In Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397678.aspx)

Comment: It's a bit more tricky than that. If someone registers with 'Andi', then your algorithm will count the occurrences of every name starting with 'Andi', including 'Andie' for instance

Comment: Got you :) wait its 3 at night let me first sleep a bit :)

Comment: Ok before that during save save every name as andi_0 andi_1 snd to match the search do a search of andi_ or anobik_ . And while displying trim from _ to string length. Is that case u get to add up numbers and show the name by trimming :)